# Is there a quantum interpretation which holds that quantum mechanics completely cease to apply at a certain level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, decoherence

An interpretation which holds that there is a sharp threshold between quantum objects and classical objects.

If there is such an interpretation: how is the threshold itself explained in the framework of the interpretation?; at what "level" does the threshold appear?

Comment: There can't be such an interpretation, because it would contradict the actual QM and thus be a distinct *theory* rather than an interpretation of QM.

Answer (score 0):

copied from wikipedia:

"The *thermal de Broglie wavelength* is roughly the average de Broglie wavelength of particles in an ideal gas at a specified temperature
$$\lambda_{th} = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2\pi m k_B T}}$$
(see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength). We can take the average interparticle spacing in the gas to be approximately $(V/N)^{1/3}$ where V is the volume and N is the number of particles. When the thermal de Broglie wavelength is much smaller than the interparticle distance, the gas can be considered to be a classical or Maxwell–Boltzmann gas. On the other hand, when the thermal de Broglie wavelength is on the order of or larger than the interparticle distance, quantum effects will dominate and the gas must be treated as a Fermi gas or a Bose gas, depending on the nature of the gas particles. The critical temperature is the transition point between these two regimes, and at this critical temperature, the thermal wavelength will be approximately equal to the interparticle distance."